# C++ Strings getting printed as hex, when that isnt the purpose

Tags: c++, arrays, hex, cout

im working on a project for school where we are supposed to create a Contact book.
I stumbled on to a problem where my program prints out strings as hexa symbols, i have never encountered this before and have no idea on how to combat it.

The strings are getting printed out on the terminal from an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int unikapersoner = 75;
string I_namn[unikapersoner];
string T_Nummer[unikapersoner];

void addcontact() {
    char Fullname[50];
    char TelefonNummer[50];
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Ange det fullständiga namnet du vill spara till kontaktboken.. "
         << endl;
    cin.getline(Fullname, 50);
    cout << "Ange telefonnummeret till personen som du vill spara.. " << endl;
    cin.getline(TelefonNummer, 50);

    for(int i = 0; i < unikapersoner; i++) {
        if(T_Nummer[i] == "\0") { // Letar efter tom index.
            I_namn[i] = Fullname;
            T_Nummer[i] = TelefonNummer;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void listALLcontacts() {
    cout << "/Kontakter/." << endl;
    cout << "=================================" << endl;
    int nr = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < unikapersoner; i++) {
        if(T_Nummer[i] != "\0") {
            nr++;
            cout << "#" << nr << " " << I_namn << " " << T_Nummer << endl;
            cout << "- - - - - - - - -" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "=================================" << endl;
    if(nr == 0) {
        cout << "Du har inga kontakter i din telefonbok..";
    }
}
int main() {
    int terminalval;
    system("CLS");

    do {
        cout << "Din telefonbok!" << endl;
        cout << "1 : Ange ny Kontakt" << endl;
        cout << "2 : Se nuvarande Kontakter" << endl;
        cout << "3 : Uppdatera kontakt" << endl;
        cout << "4 : Radera kontakt" << endl;
        cout << "5 : Avsluta" << endl;
        cout << "Ange ditt val.." << endl;
        cin >> terminalval;

        switch(terminalval) {
        case 1:
            addcontact();

            break;
        case 2:
            listALLcontacts();
            break;
        case 3:
            updatecontacts();
            break;
        case 4:
            deletecontact();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Är ett felaktigt kommando! " << endl;
        }
    } while(terminalval != 5);
}
```

Some outputs could for example be **"#1 0x123123fb123 0x213g2134z13"**
I would as always appreciate all the help i could get!
Thank you.

Comment: I added the missing headers, but the code is still not a MRE as @Ron pointed out. Add the missing functions too - or remove the calls to them if they are not needed to show the problem.

Comment: What are the inputs you used to get your result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the addresses of the arrays `I_namn` and `T_Nummer` in the function `listALLcontacts` here:

```
cout << "#" << nr << " " << I_namn << " " << T_Nummer << endl;
```

You should use the index, `i`, to print the found entry:

```
cout << "#" << nr << " " << I_namn[i] << " " << T_Nummer[i] << endl;
```

---

A note unrelated to the problem you asked about:

You do a few comparisons like this

```
if(T_Nummer[i] == "\0")
```

which isn't needed. `"\0"` is actually 2 `char`s long, consisting of the `\0` you've put there and then a terminating `\0`, so just do

```
if(T_Nummer[i] == "")
```

or even better:

```
if(T_Nummer[i].empty())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, and also the extra tips!

Comment: @Gruffis You're welcome ... och lycka till! :-)